# React Native how to use passProps in NavigatorIOS component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Here is my code:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress = { () => {

    this.props.nav.push({
      component:  Movie,
      title: movie.title,
      passProps: {movie: movie},
    });

  }}>
```

When I press the button, the navigator transfers to a movie detail page (`Movie`), and when I do `this.props.movie` in the Movie component, it turns out that `this.props` is undefined. I know I am in the wrong way, so what is the correct way? Or other solution to pass property to the `Movie` component?

Any help will be appreciate! & Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the movie data coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I've found the reason. It's not about where the movie data come from, but because I misunderstood the [lifecycle of the component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html). I use `this.props.movie` in the `getInitialState` function of the Movie component which is apparently wrong.

Thanks for your help~

Answer (score 0):

I assume movie is in your props scope? If so, then maybe you just need to scope it. Was movie.title getting passed through? Try this...

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress = { () => {

this.props.nav.push({
  component:  Movie,
  title: this.props.movie.title,
  passProps: {movie: this.props.movie},
});

}}>
```